# Calling min_order_qty on each product modifier option

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, ecommerce

I am creating a product info page, where you can select a product modifier (e.g. size, flavor), I have an issue.

First of all, according the Expresso-Store docs:

**min_order_qty**

> The minimum order quantity for the product. If the product has more
>   than one SKU, this will be the maximum of all minimum order
>   quantities. If the product does not have any minimum order quantity,
>   this will return 1. Useful for pre-populating the item_qty field:

Found that it actually returns the minimum of all min order quantities.

Changed the Product.php file on line 132 from:

```
if ($item->min_order_qty < $min_order_qty) {
```

to...

```
if ($item->min_order_qty > $min_order_qty) {
```

That seemed to resolve the issue of not returning the maximum of minimum order quantities.

Lastly, the issue remains that I need to be able to retrieve the individual min_order_qty's for each modifier option so that I may, for instance, update the Quantity field in the document dynamically.

Since the fields allow you to map a minimum order quantity to each stock (SKU) variant, I expected to a method to retrieve each of these quantity values.

Attached is an image of an example product modifier options for context:
[image: Example of product modifier options with different minimum order quantities.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer comes from Manuel over at DevDemon Support.

> Thank you for the follow up! And indeed the fix is correct, we already encountered this and it was fixed for Store 2.4.
>
> And for the minimum order qty inside the modifiers loop? Already
>   possible, just not documented.

```
{modifier_options}
    {option_name} - Min Order Qty. {option_min_order_qty}
{/modifier_options}
```

Tested this and it does indeed work without a hitch.